# C# XAML- adding navigation buttons to a browser toolbar

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, exception

I have added a web browser to my C# application using the following XAML code:

```
<WebBrowser Name="rivBrowser" Height="550" Width="620" Margin="0, 40, 0, 0" Visibility="Visible" />
    <DockPanel>
        <ToolBarTray DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <ToolBar Header="File">
                <Button Command="New" Content="New" ToolBar.OverflowMode="Always" />
                <Button Command="Open" Content="Open" ToolBar.OverflowMode="Always" />
                <Button Command="Save" Content="Save" ToolBar.OverflowMode="Always" />
            </ToolBar>
            <ToolBar Header="Edit" Margin="5.4,0,-5.4,0">
                <Button Command="Cut" Content="Cut" ToolBar.OverflowMode="Always" />
                <Button Command="Copy" Content="Copy" ToolBar.OverflowMode="Always" />
                <Button Command="Paste" Content="Paste" ToolBar.OverflowMode="Always" />
            </ToolBar>
            <ToolBar Margin="9.2,0,-8.2,0">
                <Button Command="Back" ToolTip="Return to the previous page"/>
                <Image Source="C:\Users\elgan\workspace\browser\riviam_windows\Images\navigateBack.png" Width="20" Height="20" Margin="0,0,0,2.4" />
            </ToolBar>
            <ToolBar Margin="16.4,0,-16.2,0" >
                <Button Command="Forward" ToolTip="Proceed to the next page" />
                <Image Source="C:\Users\elgan\workspace\browser\riviam_windows\Images\navigateForward.png" Width="20" Height="20" />
            </ToolBar>
        </ToolBarTray>



    </DockPanel>
```

However, I'm getting some exceptions with the 'Forward' and 'Back' navigation buttons that I'm trying to add to the toolbar. The exceptions say:

> Exception thrown
>
> > 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll

and

> Additional information: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '73' and line position '22'.

That line is the line `<Button Command="Back" ToolTip="Return to the previous page"/>`

It's the button I want to use to allow the user to navigate back to the previous page displayed in the browser- but I'm not sure that I'm doing this correctly... Should I be calling a method from my C# code here? How do I do that?

I've not used C# in about 6 years, so am not very familiar with it or how it works...

Comment: Command="Back" That does not seem right. As of you dont bind command to string.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't say if you are using the MVVM pattern or not I'll assume you don't.

In this case, you'll want to subscribe to the `Click` event of the `Button` rather than using a `Command`

For example :

```
<Button Click="GoForward_OnClick" ToolTip="Proceed to the next page" />
```

And on your code-behind (yourfile.xaml.cs) you'll have the method called when the button is clicked :

```
private void GoForward_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Your code logic goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Command should be pointing to a DelegateCommand object on your viewmodel. Here is a sample:

View:

```
<Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
```

ViewModel:

```
public DelegateCommand SaveCommand { get; private set; }

public SampleViewModel()
{
    SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(Save);
}

private void Save()
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use built in ApplicationCommands the you should use such syntax of `Command` like `ApplicationCommands.Cut`.

For example:

```
<Button Content="Cut" Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut"/>
<Button Content="Copy"  Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy"/>
<Button Content="Paste" Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste"/>
```

MSDN has a good article about a list of [available Application Commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **CancelPrint**   - Gets the value that represents the Cancel Print command.
> System_CAPS_pubpropertySystem_CAPS_static
>
> **Close** - Gets the value that represents the Close command.
>
> **ContextMenu** - Gets the value
> that represents the Context Menu command.
>
> > > > ...